# jQuery and PHP - It saves a weird value into DB

Tags: jquery

I have this script.

```
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
    $(window).load(function(){
        window.loadIframe = function(frame) {
           var link = $(frame).attr('src');
           $.post('link.php', {'link': link}, function (txt) {});
        }
    });
</script>
```

If I replace `$.post('a.php', {'link': link}, function (txt) {});` for `alert(link)` it will display a link: example(http://www.example.com/**123-a-b-c-d-e-f-0**), ok.

Then, in the link.php I have this code:

```
<? 
...
$link = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'link', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); 
    mysql_query("insert into prueba values ('', '$link')"); 
...
?>
```

When I check the database, the value inserted isn't the full link, is 123-------0

Where is the problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: You're filtering out non-numbers for some reason

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT`. From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php):

> Remove all characters except digits, plus and minus sign.

Comment: omg hahahahah what a silly mistake. it's made by my little knowledge, thank you!

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us. Sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes.

Answer (score -2):

The post value that was sent was under `link.php`.

Use `$_POST['link.php']`.

Also [**please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).